# Extjs combobox is empty after loading the data to the store

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

Could you help me to figure out why the code is not working. I combo box is empty after loading the data

```
var groupComboBoxStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['value', 'name']
});
var groupComboBox = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Groups',
    store: groupComboBoxStore,
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'value',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
groupComboBoxStore.loadData([{name: 'name1', value: 'value1'}], false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks to be a bug or not handled implementation in Extjs I changed the code to be

```
var groupComboBox = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Groups',
    store: []
});
groupComboBox.store.loadData([['value1'], ['value2']], false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant set your data in the store definition instead of using `loadData` method.

```
   var groupComboBoxStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      fields: ['value', 'name'],
      data : [
         {name: 'name1', value: 'value1'}
      ]
   });

   var groupComboBox = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
      fieldLabel: 'Groups',
      store: groupComboBoxStore,
      displayField: 'name',
      valueField: 'value',
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
   });
```

Comment: well but that is like creating a new store each time data is changed, sometimes happens when the data is changing but not remotely, then one just needs to recreate the store object and re bind it to the combo